# What is the use of fflush(stdout) in C and how to use it?

Tags: c, buffer, stdout, fflush

I searched the web for this, but can't find satisfactory result.

Can anyone show me the use of `fflush(stdout)` in C and a simple code that can be run with and without `fflush(stdout)` so that it is easy to figure out the difference in the output. Also please explain the same in simplest form.

Comment: You searched web, but did not include SO itself?

Comment: I asked for a simple code with and without `fflush(stdout)` as in the case of `stdin`. So that it's easy to figure out the difference in the execution. If you know a simple code then please post it here or in the comments.

Comment: Please read the linked dupes, they should be able to answer your questions.

Comment: The two links you posted doesn't cleared my doubt. The second link is about the rules of automatic `stdout` but I asked for the use of `fflush` and the first question which is having a verified answer doesn't run the same as described on my system i.e. the expected output is the real output not the one mentioned. Please brother if you know then post just a simple program which can describe its use. I had wasted a lot of time in understanding this but being a novice it's difficult. Although I understood the concept of `fflush(stdin)` but `stdout` is tough.

Comment: FYI, `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior, don't do that.

Comment: @Neeraj-Kumar-Coder _... doesn't run the same as described on my system_... see why   (different stream buffering): http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/Stream-buffering.html

Comment: and I think this answer [Why would I need use fflush on stdout before writing to stderr?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42660873) exactly shows the case with and without the call.